Build error in visual studio community in a C# avalonia project when deleting a user control
I'm getting a ANX0002 error when trying to build a C# avalonia project right after I'd deleted a user control

unable to resolve type [control-name] from namespace [namespace] line 274, position 7 in CSC.

I've removed every reference to the user control in xaml and C# code, but it still gives me the error.

I've checked the project file as well and there is no reference.
I've tried unloading/reloading the project and deleting the bin obj files without success in building
and of course cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Is there anything else I should check or try?

The error message tell you where is the problem exactly, go to line 274, position 7 in fileName and check this location and maybe few line before it if it axaml file !!

Unfortunately CSC is the compiler. There is no file with 274 or more lines which is called CSC...

I try to replicate the error by adding non-existing view i get this error which is different error code, but the description is almost the same... so I believe that you still have reference for that control somewhere in your code follow the @jack answer will be good approach ... if the project size is small you can copy every thing to new project and run the project every step until you find the problem.

Well... it was indeed a xaml reference. The number of files was too large to check one by one, so I did search using the search option in visual studio which insisted on missing the reference. I tried both the reference search and the global search options! I also tried windows search for text (not only filenames) which also revealed nothing! At last a github search revealed the reference (the 2nd time I tried it). I can't figure out why the searches failed, although I waited enough before giving up

The problem seems to be related to the user control. You need to find the related xaml code or c# code ,delete them and finally rebuild the solution.
Please look at the following steps:

Perform a Global Search for the Control Name

Press Ctrl+Shift+F in Visual Studio to open the global search window. Enter the name of the deleted control to search across the entire project, including XAML and code-behind files.

Clean Up References in XAML Files

In the search results, find the XAML files that still reference the deleted control:
Remove the xmlns declarations related to the deleted control (namespace imports).

Delete any UI tags related to the deleted control.

Update Code-Behind Files
In the search results, locate the code-behind files:
Remove or update any references to the deleted control's namespace and class.
If the control's functionality needs to be retained, replace it with an Avalonia standard control or update it with other valid controls, namespaces, and class names.

Save and Rebuild the Project

Save all modified files and click Rebuild Solution to ensure all errors are resolved.

The problem is that I've searched for any references and I had already deleted them everywhere. No reference comes up when searching for references using the related option of visual studio or global search. I've removed an entry in the .proj file as well. And - as I already said - I tried removing bin, obj etc to see what happens. Could it be .git related files?
